# Yesterday, Firefox stopped loading gmail. SSL cert is fine

Tags: firefox, ssl, gmail

Corrupted Content Error

The site at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

```
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Firefox version 56.0b9. OSX

I haven't modified Firefox settings in months

Comment: @GrahamPerrin You are right, I submitted that comment, to the wrong question.  Which is now deleted which means you can delete your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this issue by unregistering the service worker

1. In your browser, go to about:serviceworkers
2. Find the entry for Gmail
3. Click unregister
4. Refresh Gmail

Answer (score 1):

In the web console (Waterfox 56.2.6 on FreeBSD-CURRENT) I see:

> Failed to load ‘https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/’. A ServiceWorker passed a redirected Response to FetchEvent.respondWith() while RedirectMode is not ‘follow’.

#### Workarounds

You can un-register the service worker ([the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1379937/84988)) but this is not a persistent workaround; the worker may reappear.

I find it quicker to reload the page without caches e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-reload or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> but again, this is not a persistent workaround.

#### Related

[Corrupted Content Error when opening GMail | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/1232773) (2018-09-07)

[mozilla.support.firefox › Gmail corruption – Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.support.firefox/pTiAC-eOF3Q/VkQNFjHCFwAJ) (2018-09-17)

[Problème d'accès à GMAIL - Google - Espace Geckozone](https://forums.mozfr.org/viewtopic.php?t=139461) (2018-10-17)

[Firefox Gmail Corrupted Content Error - Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122285/firefox-gmail-corrupted-content-error) (2018-11-16)

[Service Worker failure - Redirected response while RedirectMode is not "follow" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008332/service-worker-failure-redirected-response-while-redirectmode-is-not-follow) – I'll add a reply there.

#### Postscript

Mozilla bug [1495275 - Corrupted Content Error for gmail](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1495275)

Answer (score -1):

Corrupted Content Error - Gmail's error Message

The site at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.

Here is the FIX:
Error that was easily fixed in Linux (Debian 8.x - 32 Bit & Ver 60.6 FFox)

1. From Gmail (in Firefox) CNTL SHIFT R will let you reload page but doesn't
   fix problem.  (SHIFT Mouse LEFT CLICK on refresh page also works.)
2. Try CNTL SHIFT E to get into the editor, and select storage, then cache,
   then the top line (left side) and delete that entry.  It will have the same
   date as the Firefox CRASH, and the same text as error message statement.
   I had to delete the next two lines also to make it work 100%.
3. Close editor with CNTL SHIFT E, and everything works correctly when
   loading Gmail